# Move icon to the left in list

Tags: html, css

What do I need in my CSS to move the text and the fa-check circle to the left, so its placed right by the border of the list group? Check image.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Test1</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Test2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Test3</li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKVnU.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.list-group-item {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

will remove any padding from the list item that is pushing your check mark over.

if the check mark itself has padding or margin, you could give the `.fa-check-circle` negative margin.

also, you have a stray `</a>` tag in your first list item

Answer (score -1):

1-Style your CSS or use padding as per your required alignment
2-Put your list in the container first.

.list-group-item{
text-align:right
}